# How to solve Could not execute JDBC batch update exception in Mysql with Jboss?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

I am trying to load sample application on JBOSS with MySQL . During the deployment i am getting `Could not execute JDBC batch update` exception . 
This is the complete stack dump :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into my_db.snmp_settings (address, enabled, max_count_in_memory, rocommunity, skip_unknown, storage_period, storage_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637) [spring-orm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.convertHibernateAccessException(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:303) [spring-orm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:282) [spring-orm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58) [spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) [spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163) [spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.sample.service.singleton.SnmpSettingsServiceImpl.initializeSnmpSettings(SnmpSettingsServiceImpl.java:105) [sample-core-6.4.0.jar:]
        ... 35 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at com.test.sample.dao.hibernate.exception.AbstractSQLExceptionConverter.convert(AbstractSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [sample-dao-api-6.4.0.jar:]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:262) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:178) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at com.test.sample.dao.singleton.SingletonHibernateDAO.execute(SingletonHibernateDAO.java:108) [sample-dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at com.test.sample.dao.singleton.SingletonHibernateDAO.saveOrUpdate(SingletonHibernateDAO.java:80) [sample-dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_41]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.6.0_41]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.6.0_41]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) [rt.jar:1.6.0_41]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) [spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 41 more

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'address' cannot be null
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:1077)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        ... 58 more
```

In mysql table , I am using following table .

```
create table snmp_settings (
  id bigint not null,
  address varchar(64),
  enabled smallint not null,
  max_count_in_memory integer,
  storage_period integer,
  rocommunity varchar(128) not null,
  skip_unknown smallint not null,
  storage_type integer not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

What is the reasons for the error execute JDBC batch update ? Any suggestions or help please ?

Comment: The reason is that you try to store null into the column address, which can not be null (despite what your table definition says): *Column 'address' cannot be null*.

Comment: so how to should i avoid such problems ? should i modify the table defintion? or any idea?

Comment: First you need to wonder why MySQL rejects a null value although you calin that the address is null. Maybe you actually don't insert into that table. Maybe the actual table definition is not what you posted. Then you need to decide if the column should actually be nullable or not, and fix the definition accordingly. And then you need to decide whether it's normal or not for this code to insert null into this column, and fix the code accordingly.

Comment: thanks for suggestion !! i will look on it